Implementing additional health checks for AppServices
I currently have a /health endpoint to monitor the overall availability of my service.
Since some processes in my Api are dependent on external (non Azure) Apis, I implemented an additional endpoint called /health-third-party.
In production the Api is deployed behind an Api Management Service (with token authentication).
What is best practice in this kind of scenario?
Exposing the additional endpoint without auth?
Azure functions? But this seems to be quite an effort for such a simple task..
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

What is the framework of your App?

You can configure API Management to excuse the /health-third-party endpoint from requiring a token, so external monitoring tools (or Azure Monitor) can easily check it.

If health checks need to remain secured, consider using a managed identity or OAuth token request to allow Azure Monitor (or similar) to authenticate when accessing /health-third-party.

@SureshChikkam, good call to use a MI. The routes should be all secured and this is way I didn´t use Application Insights´ Activity tab for it.

@Harshitha it´s a Python based FastApi, but I am not sure if the framework does matter as I would want to have an external service that pings my API.

Can I detail it and post it as an answer ?

Using a Managed Identity (MI) for securing the routes is a great decision! Regarding Activity Tab in Application Insights, I see why you might avoid it for this case. The Activity Tab can provide visibility into operations, but it doesn’t inherently support secure access control.

@SureshChikkam which service would you recommend using instead? I cannot really see any other Service in Azure Monitor for this kind of use case

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Azure Monitor Workbooks are customizable and can securely pull data from the /health-third-party endpoint using MI. You can design a workbook to query the health endpoint at intervals and visualize the status of third-party dependencies.

Create a workbook in Azure Monitor and configure it to authenticate using MI, then periodically call the /health-third-party endpoint. You’ll get a dashboard-like view of the API’s dependencies.

In the Azure Portal, go to App Service (API). Navigate to Identity > System-assigned > Status and turn it On. Assign permissions to access the /health-third-party endpoint.

Then after go to Azure Monitor in the Azure Portal. Under Insights, select Workbooks. Click on Add Workbook to start a new one. Add a HTTP Data Source by clicking on Add query. Configure it to call the /health-third-party endpoint of the API.
Azure Monitor's Kusto Query Language:
requests
| where url contains "/health-third-party"  // Filter for the health check endpoint
| project timestamp, name, resultCode, success, url, cloud_RoleName, duration, customDimensions 
| extend ServiceName = tostring(customDimensions["ServiceName"])  // Extract third-party service name
| extend ErrorMessage = tostring(customDimensions["ErrorMessage"])  // Optional: Extract error message
| where success == false  // Filter to show only failed checks
| summarize Failures = count() by ServiceName, bin(timestamp, 1h)  // Count failures by service and time bin

